# On change on a select, get the input right after

Tags: jquery

How I can select the next `input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]` on select change in this code please ?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th width="60%">Date</th>
      <th width="40%">Price of the night $</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>
        <select name="BIL_RateId[]" class="form-control">
          <option value="0">Custom price</option>
          <option value="3">Special</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" name="BIL_Rate[]" class="form-control" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I tried:

```
select = $('select[name="BIL_RateId[]"]');
select.find('input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]').val();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example which may help you:

```js
$('select').change(function(){
   var $this=$(this).val();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('[name="BIL_Rate[]"]').val($this)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th width="60%">Date</th>
      <th width="40%">Price of the night $</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>
        <select name="BIL_RateId[]" class="form-control">
          <option value="0">Custom price</option>
          <option value="3">Special</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" name="BIL_Rate[]" class="form-control" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What's happen if I have more than one set of select/input ?

Comment: Check the update, now it will change only in the same row

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This snippet allows you to focus on the next `input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]`

If you want to get the value from the `input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]`, just change

`$('input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]').focus();`

FOR

`$('input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]').val();`

```js
$(function(){

    $('select[name="BIL_RateId[]"]').on('change', function(){
        $('input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]').focus();
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th width="60%">Date</th>
      <th width="40%">Price of the night $</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>
        <select name="BIL_RateId[]" class="form-control">
          <option value="0">Custom price</option>
          <option value="3">Special</option>
        </select>
      </th>
      <td>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" name="BIL_Rate[]" class="form-control" required="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What's happen if I have more than one set of select/input ?

Comment: @PacPac As long as your other selects/inputs don't have the same name as this select/input (BIL_RateId[] / BIL_Rate[]), it won't happen annything to them :)

Comment: `select.find('input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]').` will not work. try `closest('tr').find('input......').`

Comment: @PacPac This code will only work for selects/inputs with name BIL_RateId[] / BIL_Rate[] ---> as specified by the code: `$('select[name="BIL_RateId[]"]')` and `$('input[name="BIL_Rate[]"]')`

Comment: @Sysix My bad, I left that code without intention, it was copied from the OP and forgot to delete it! Already edited the snippet.. Thanks :)